# Why do I get different output from a function by passing a string as it is versus a variable which is equal to a string in a function?

Tags: python, graph, syntax, nodes, python-itertools

I'm having this problem here:

```
def findPaths(neighborDict, start, end, prev=0, path=[],distance = 0):
    path = path + [start]
    if not prev == 0:
        for i in neighborDict[start]:
            if i[0] is prev:
                distance = distance + i[1]
    if start == end:
        path.append(distance)
        return [path]

    paths = []

    for node in neighborDict[start]:
        if node[0] not in path:
            newpaths = findPaths(neighborDict, node[0], end, start, path,distance)
            for i in newpaths:
                paths.append(i)

    return paths
```

This code is to find all path in a weighted graph. 
Here neighborDict stores all the nodes.

I fill up neighborDict with some nodes. I then create a series of two random nodes using itertools

```
neighborDict = {'1': [('3', 32), ('2', 8)], '2': [('1', 8), ('3', 2), ('4', 4)], '3': [('1', 32), ('2', 2), ('4', 16)], '4': [('5', 1), ('3', 16), ('2', 4)], '5': [('4', 1)]}


for i in range(numCities):
perms.append(str(i+1))

combs =[x for x in itertools.combinations(perms,2)]
```

Now, I'm getting different outputs by giving say,

```
findPaths(neighborDict,combs[0][1],combs[0][0])
```

vs

```
findPaths(neighborDict,'2','1')
```

Here, combs[0][1] = '2' and combs[0][0] = '1'. Hence, they should give the same output.

Output 1 is:-  [['2', '1', 0], ['2', '3', '1', 32], ['2', '4', '3', '1', 48]]
Output 2 is:- [['2', '1', 8], ['2', '3', '1', 34], ['2', '4', '3', '1', 52]]

Comment: please fix your indentation

Comment: a provide a [mcve]. Maybe a side-effect prevents from giving twice the same result with same inputs

Comment: First time posting. Fixed it now. Sorry

Comment: Got it. It was because I was using is instead of ==.

Comment: aah yes don't use `is` as it may or not work, due to the way the strings are interned. Don't use `is` _ever_ except for singletons